# Need conversion of Stripe cURL api call into axios

Tags: curl, axios, stripe-payments

`curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/cus_H6fiYnqt188gJY/sources \ -u sk_test_HMDGpZwmHEavh8xi8fQCgrwL: \ -d object=card \ -d limit=3 \ -G`

what are `-u`and `-G` here? 
Also what is equivalent call into axios for above request?

Comment: Please note that you should only do this server-side - you should never allow your Secret Key to be sent client side - and in that case you're likely better off just using https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-u` or `--user` is used for authentication providing the `<user:password>` or whatever auth mechanism the backend requires.
In stripe, for `-u`, you have to pass the API Secret that you can retrieve from your stripe dashboard.

The `-G`, or `--get` will convert the data that you're providing in the call from an object, to query parameters like `<your_URL>?object=card` as per your question.

You can read more here:
https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G

Now, when it comes to Axios, you'll do something like:

```js
export const yourFunc = async () => {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${stripeAPISecret}`
    }
  }
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://stripeapiurlsomething' + '?object=card', body, config)
    console.log("res: ", res)
    return res;
  catch (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
    return null;
  }
}
```